# setState() doesn't update value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update state of my component and it's not working. I have Main page container component => nested Navbar container component => nested NavItem UI component. Also on Main page I have AddNavItem container component which should add item to Navbar. It looks like this:

```
Main
|
|--NavBar
|   |
|   |--NavItem
|
|--AddNavItem
```

This is my Main page code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from '../nav/Navbar'
import AddNavItem from '../fields/AddNavItem'

class Main extends Component {
    state = {
        items: [
            {id: 1, name: 'Услуги', link: 'services'},
            {id: 2, name: 'Цены', link: 'prices'},
            {id: 3, name: 'Как это работает?', link: 'works'},
        ]
    }

    addNavItem = (item) => {
        this.setState((state) => {
            let newItems = [...state.items];
            newItems.unshift(item)
            console.log(newItems);
            return { 
               items: newItems
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar items={ this.state.items }/>
                <AddNavItem addNavItem={ this.addNavItem }/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

The problem is that I always get old array with 3 initial obj even after `addNavItem` is firing. `<Navbar />` still gets array with 3 element. I have read about async setState and makes as describe in doc https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html What have I doing wrong?

**UPD:** I changed code (unshift) to return array, not a length of the array. Console log shows me that I get new array with 4 obj

**UPD:** My complete code for all components:

Navbar

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NavItem from './NavItem';

class Navbar extends Component {
    state = {
        items: this.props.items,
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="centered navbar grey">
                <h2>MyReact</h2>
                <ul>
                    <NavItem items={ this.state.items }/>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    };
}

export default Navbar;
```

NavItem:

```
import React from 'react';

const NavItem = ({ items }) => { 
    const menuItemList = items.map((item) => {
        return (
            <li key={item.id}>
                { item.name }
            </li>
        );
    })
    return (
        <div>
            { menuItemList }
        </div>
    )
}

export default NavItem;
```

AddNavItem:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AddNavItem extends Component {
    state = {
        id: Math.random(),
        name: null,
        link: null
    }

    handleInput = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.id]: e.target.value,
        });
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.addNavItem(this.state);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="centered flex-column-centered">
                <form onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit }>
                    <h4 className="labelField">Название раздела:</h4>

                    <input 
                        className="inputField" 
                        type="text"
                        id="name" 
                        placeholder="укажите название" 
                        onChange={ this.handleInput } />

                    <h4 className="labelField">URL:</h4>

                    <input
                        className="inputField" 
                        type="text"
                        id="link" 
                        placeholder="укажите ссылку" 
                        onChange={ this.handleInput } />

                    <button className="submitBtn">Добавить</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AddNavItem;
```

Comment: unshift reurns the new length of the array.

Comment: the `unsift` method adds one or more elements to the beginning of an array and `returns the new length of the array`. Instead, could set the state by using `[...this.state.items, item]`

Comment: @SteveBohmbach I changed my code to get array, not a length. It still doesn't work. See my UPD

Comment: @Balanced02 I can't add it to the end. I need it in the start ((

Comment: then you revert to `[item, ...this.state.items]`

Comment: I updated my answer, the issue lied in your NavBar component.  You weren't updating state on the items prop changes.  You can either add a componentWillUpdate method to your component and update your NavBar state whenever the items prop changes, or you can just pass the items props to the NavItem component instead of items from state.

Comment: In your "Navbar"component, instead of state, use this.props.items directly in render.
```<ul>
                    <NavItem items={ this.props.items }/>
</ul>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)

> The unshift() method adds one or more elements to the beginning of an array and returns the new length of the array.

So when you try to change your state using this, it's returning the length of the array instead of the new array you're trying to update the state to. On top of that, this method is **mutable** as you are modifying the original array instead of returning a new copy of it.  I would suggest changing your code to use the [array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method instead as it keeps your state **immutable** as it returns a new array instead of modifying the original array.

Try changing your method to this instead.

```
addNavItem = (item) => {
    this.setState({ items: this.state.items.concat(item) });
}
```

**Edit:**

If you are using es6, you can use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) which also returns a new copy of the array.

```
addNavItem = (item) => {
    this.setState({ items: [...this.state.items, item] });
}
```

**Edit 2:**
In your Navbar component, you're setting this.props.items to state when it initializes and then you don't update your state when this.props.items change.

You don't need state for this component, I would change your NavBar component to look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import NavItem from './NavItem';

const Navbar = (props) => {
        return (
            <div className="centered navbar grey">
                <h2>MyReact</h2>
                <ul>
                    <NavItem items={ props.items }/>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
}

export default Navbar;
```

**Edit 3:**

If you want to keep your items inside state in your NavBar component, then you need to watch for updates being made to the items props on that component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NavItem from './NavItem';

class Navbar extends Component {
    state = {
        items: this.props.items,
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      if (this.props.items!== prevProps.items) {
        this.setState({ items: this.props.items });
      }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="centered navbar grey">
                <h2>MyReact</h2>
                <ul>
                    <NavItem items={ this.state.items }/>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    };
}

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: To clarify, when you mutate state, react will not render any state changes that were made.  Which is why you might be able to console.log(this.state.items) and see the updated array even though it isn't being shown in the UI

Comment: Can you explain what errors you're receiving?  This should work.

Comment: no any errors in console, I expect to get new element in my NavBar but it's not (( see scr prntscr.com/kx349i

Comment: The reason is because you're setting the items to state in your navbar component.  You dont have a way of updating your state in the NavBar

Comment: Instead of setting it in state, change your navbar component to use this.props.items instead of this.state.items

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct if it worked! Thank you.

Comment: Yeah! it started to adding a new Item. But I can't figure out why I can't set my items in the state through state = {items: this.props.items}. Why I have to <NavItem items={ this.props.items }/> Can you explain?

Comment: When you set your state inside the state declaration, that's only going to set that state when the component initializes.  So when it's first rendered to the screen, it renders with the props.  However, it doesn't update when props change.  To do that, you have to use the lifecycle hook componentDidUpdate https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate which you can use to listen for prop changes made to the state.

Comment: Or you could just pass the props directly to the component without setting it to state.  That works to.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [3,4,5]
console.log(arr.unshift(3,5))
```

```
addNavItem = (item) => {
    let newItems = [...this.state.items];
    newItems.unshift(item)
    this.setState({
            items: newItems
        }
    });
}
```

Now you are updating the array and adding the elements to the begining of it, which i assume you wanted and is why you picked upshift. you are then setting the sate equal to the updated array you have.

Comment: what do you get in             console.log(newItems);

Comment: new array of 4 elements. Look at my scr http://prntscr.com/kx349i Thanks for helping me

Comment: can i see the ode for navbar now?

Comment: sorry, i cant find where the issue is. If you are using the chrom browser they have a good react developer tool. it can show you current state and props of a component. it can also highlight things that are re rendered. I would start there and figure out exactly where the data is lost.

Answer (score 0):

```
addNavItem = (item) => {
  this.setState((prevState) => {items: [...prevState.items, item]})
}
```

This should work.